# Insert a fix char in every occurrence of another fix char

Tags: java, string

I want to insert a fix character in every occurrence of any other fix character. How can I accomplish this in Java. 
Ex: if the input is "testnet", the o/p should be 'z' inserted in front of every 't'. That is -
Input : testnet (can be of variable length)
output: ztesztnezt. 
This is what I have tried so far. But its not working fully.

```
public class InsertAtEveryOccurrenceOfCharacter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "testnet";
        int len = str.length();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);


        for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
            if(str.charAt(i)=='t') {

                sb = sb.insert(i, "z");
            }

        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Comment: `str = str.replaceAll("t", "zt");`

Comment: Have you considered using `.replaceAll("t", "zt")`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: If you stil want to stick with index iteration, you need to increment `i` a second time if you found/inserted a character, otherwise it will keep finding the same character over and over again, resulting in an infinite loop. Also you would need to check the `StringBuilder`'s size inside the for-loop instead of caching it in the `len` variable, as the String size changes during the loop

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I am using .replace(), because its a bit hard to find the solution by iterating. Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `replace()` method from `String` class. It looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "testnet";
    str = str.replace("t","zt");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

The Output is:

> ztesztnezt

For more information about replace method, you can check out the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)).

Comment: `replaceAll` is for replacing using regex - use `replace` for normal Strings

Comment: This solution could not pass all the hidden test cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple fix for your requirement(no need to loop through the string)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "testnet";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("t", "zt"));

}
```